# Remote debugging using gnu DDD

Tags: linux, debugging, ddd-debugger

#### Question:

- Is it possible to **debug**, when the **target** is on a **remote host**?

**Example:**

```
 # ddd --debugger /usr/bin/bashdb <sript-name> (on remote host)
```

Comment: You might get a better answer on stackoverflow

Comment: How can I migrate this question to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use gdbserver on the target (remote) machine [as explained there.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gdbserver)
Then follow the config steps for gdb remote debugging (look up the gdb doc), typing the commands in the ddd console window (it's a pass through to the gdb prompt).

This could be something like this (if your link to the target were an USB to serial link, for instance):

```
(gdb) set remotebaud 115200
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyUSB0
```

or

```
(gdb) target remote the-target:2345
```

to debug the gdbserver on IP the-target,using TCP port 2345.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is ssh into the remote host, and set the `$DISPLAY` variable to point to your local host, so that ddd's GUI opens there:

First lookup your current `$DISPLAY`:

```
mylocalhost:~> echo $DISPLAY
mylocalhost:1
```

Assuming that your current X-client is on port 1.

Now setup the remote `$DISPLAY` to point to your local machine:

```
mylocalhost:~> ssh remotehost
remotehost:~> setenv DISPLAY mylocalhost:1
```

Now fire up ddd:

```
remotehost:~> ddd <whatever parameters you want>
```

Note that you may have to open up your local X-client to remote connections before you do this.  This is how:

```
mylocalhost:~> xhost +
```

Comment: this would be running *ddd* remotely, as opposed to running *ddd* locally and debugging a remote program.  (just to clarify what this does.  it may be a suitable alternative for the OP's purpose, whatever that may be.)

Comment: ssh can also be set up to tunnel the X connection securely back to your display server.  You can do this on the command line by specifying `-o ForwardX11=yes`

Answer (score 0):

Try xming server + putty portable, it's awesome for remote debug. I'm using it to debug my code inside a linux VM without problems.

http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/
https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY